# MySQL Performance comparison between loading comma separted vs fixed-width large file

Tags: mysql, performance, mariadb

I have a file with 50 Gb, 7 columns and fixed-with. I couldn't succeed to load the data in my database (MariaDB 5.5.31, Windows 7, MYISAM) that is: after 15 hours I stopped the loading process. Does comma seperated file may perform better than fixed-width?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, don't use myisam. 
Csv or fixed width, performance will be same. But if you load the dump in chunks it will be faster. Check out pt-fifo tool from Percona toolkit. It doesn't work well though if the dump contains newlines.

Comment: Thanks for answer and suggestion to use Perconia toolkit. I didn't know that and will have a look at it. If you disuade to use myisam which other engine do you suggest? I thought that myisam had a better performance loading data then, for example, innodb.

Comment: InnoDB would be the best choice unless you run something specific on a Facebook size database. MyISAM used to be more performant long time ago but since then InnoDB became much faster than MyISAM. But performance is not my concern. MyISAM is a terrible choice. It's corruption prone, it can leave the database in inconsistent state. Not to mention transactions.